# Is it possible to create a database call outside of a required loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I'm trying to display and sort an array by an average created using data from a database. I'm retrieving three variables from the database and creating an average from these values. This value is then placed inside a new array to be sorted along with the rest of the database data.

Am I right in thinking that having the SQL query inside the loop isn't a great idea? (Performance issue?)

Is there any alternative that's available? I've attached the code below:

```
    ^ database connection/query string to retrieve all data...
$result = $stmt_business_list->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$items = array();
    foreach($result as $row){

    $single_business_id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    //Query to get ALL the service, value and quality ratings for certain business
    $test_query = "SELECT * FROM rating WHERE business_id = $single_business_id";
    $test_query_stmt = $dbh->prepare($test_query);
    $test_query_stmt->execute();
    $test_row = $test_query_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $total_value = $total_quality = $total_service = 0;

        foreach($test_row as $review)
        {
            $total_value += $review['value'];
            $total_quality += $review['quality'];
            $total_service += $review['service'];
        }

    $bayesian_value = (($set_site_average_review_count * $set_site_average_review_score) + $total_value) / ($set_site_average_review_count + $business_review_count);
    $bayesian_quality = (($set_site_average_review_count * $set_site_average_review_score) + $total_quality) / ($set_site_average_review_count + $business_review_count);
    $bayesian_service = (($set_site_average_review_count * $set_site_average_review_score) + $total_service) / ($set_site_average_review_count + $business_review_count);
    $average_bayesian_rating = ($bayesian_value + $bayesian_quality + $bayesian_service) / 3;
    $average_bayesian_rating = $average_bayesian_rating;

        array_push($items, array(
        "id"=>"$single_business_id",
        "name"=>"$name",
        "value"=>"$total_value",
        "quality"=>"$total_quality",
        "service"=>"$total_service",
        "average"=>"$average_bayesian_rating"));

    echo 
    'Name: '.$name.'<br>
    Value: '.$total_value.'<br>
    Quality: '.$total_quality.'<br>
    Service: '.$total_service.'<br>
    Average: '.$average_bayesian_rating.'<br><br>';
    }
}
```

The page will be split up by a separate pagination script and will only display 6 objects at a time, but over time this may change so I do have an eye on performance as much as I can.

Comment: you're correct, having a query run within a loop will be a bottleneck for performance. it is possible to do all of this with one sql query by extending your original query that gets the business list, by joining to the ratings table and using MySQL's AVG function, and GROUP BY.

Comment: So to get the service, value and quality from the original query then simply do the calculation in the loop instead? Hmm! I'll try this!

Comment: actually the AVG function in mysql can be used to calc the average ratings, and if youre looking for a total rating score and number of ratings for each business, check out SUM and COUNT functions. Let the database do the work for you in just one query :)

Comment: It's the particular type of average I'm after that's the problem - It's not a usual average, it's weighted - 'Bayesian Average'

Answer (score 1):

SQL aggregate queries are made for this kind of thing.

Use this query to summarize the results

```
 SELECT b.name, b.id,
        SUM(value)   total_value,
        SUM(quality) total_quality,
        SUM(service) total_service,
        COUNT(*)     review_count,
        avg_reviews_per_biz
   FROM business b
   JOIN ratings r ON b.id = r.business_id
   JOIN (
          SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT business_id) / COUNT(*) avg_reviews_per_biz
            FROM ratings
        ) a ON 1=1                     
  GROUP BY b.name, b.id, avg_review_per_biz
```

This will give you one row per business showing the summed ratings and the number of ratings.  This result set will have the following columns

```
name            business name
  id            business id
  total_value   sum of value ratings for that business
  total_quality sum of quality ditto
  total_service sum of service ditto
  review_count  number of reviews for business "id"
  avg_reviews_per_biz   avg number of reviews per business
```

The last column has the same value for all rows of your query.

You can then loop over these row one business at a time doing your statistical computations.

I can't tell from your question where you're getting variables like $set_site_average_review_count, so I can't help with those computations.

You'll find that SQL aggregate querying is very powerful indeed.

Comment: Ah I just understood what you're trying to do - Not sure how I would work the average of each business, at the moment I'm working this out by a formula outside of the query

Comment: Oops, a typo in the `average_review_per_biz`. Fixed.

Comment: The query runs with the typos corrected, but the average is incorrect which is why I chose to use the Bayesian formula, something I assume cannot be done inside the query?

Comment: Lots of people do Bayesian stuff in queries. I suspect you can too. With that JOINed subquery, I was trying to show you how you might handle two-pass statistical computations.  Here's another example. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/mean-absolute-deviation/